# Is there any more efficient way to code this?

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

```
Start:
        if(fileName.Contains("$track"))
            if(musicInfo.Tag.Track.ToString() != "") {
                fileName.Replace("$track", musicInfo.Tag.Track.ToString());
            }
            else {
                switch(System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Track # missing from tag info", "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error)) {
                    case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort:
                        fileName = "ABORTED";
                        return fileName;
                    case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry:
                        goto Start;
                    case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore:
                        fileName.Replace("$track", "");
                }

            }
```

I can't think of any better way to write this, there would be 7 more blocks of this code.

Comment: I'm not sure about more efficient but the `goto` is a hated piece of code for a lot of people.. That will get your user stuck in a loop also, if filename contains track and the tag track is empty, clicking retry will just take them to the next messagebox to retry repeatedly

Comment: Dino incoming ... http://i.stack.imgur.com/thuIW.png

Comment: ehh should i just chage it to a while loop? I feel like that would just add more code, i understand that it take them to another box, that is intended so they can add any missing details to the tag then click retry.

Comment: They don't get a chance to add more details, if they click retry, the conditions that got them to that message box haven't had chance to change, so for as long as they click retry they will be stuck in the same place

Comment: the details can be added in windows explorer

Comment: What is the purpose of retry if `fileName` never changes?

Comment: @codroipo ahh yes, thank you. I didn't notice that, i have replaced the goto with fileName = "RETRY";
return fileName;

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public string GetFileName(string fileName)
{ 
  if(fileName.Contains("$track") && 
     !String.IsNullOrEmpty(musicInfo.Tag.Track.ToString())
    {
        return fileName.Replace("$track", musicInfo.Tag.Track.ToString());
    }

     var userOption = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
     "Error: Track # missing from tag info", "Error", 
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, 
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    switch(userOption) 
    {
      case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort:
          return  "ABORTED";
      case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry:
          return GetFileName(fileName);
      case System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore:
          return fileName.Replace("$track", "");
     }
}
```

Comment: Recursion does not look appropriate here,

Comment: You are right, extracting it to a different method should be better.

Comment: I have 7 more blocks of the code above, here is a link: http://pastebin.com/W8RMh68F